# Polymer: When to use detached? When not to?

Tags: polymer-1.0

Right now I would think if I use

`document.addEventListener` in the `attached` function

I should use `document.removeEventListener` in the `detached` function.

Also I'm using firebase so I'm thinking when I use `firebase.on()` I should also use `firebase.off()`.

Probably `setInterval` as well
Are there other things to consider?